# Code after yield return is executed

Tags: c#, yield-return

Consider the following example:

```
class YieldTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var res = Create(new string[] { "1 12 123", "1234", "12345" });
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> Create(IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        foreach(string s in strings)
        {
            yield return s.Length;
            if(s.Contains(' '))
            {
                string[] tokens = s.Split(' ');
                foreach(string t in tokens)
                {
                    yield return t.Length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The call to `Create` returns {8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.

What really confuses me is that the code after the yield return statement is executed.
(Why would they name it `yield return` and not just `yield` ??) 
The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) tells us

> When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method,
>   expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained.

What does that mean? Where does a return occur? What is an iterator method?

Comment: An iterator method is what you have written. When the code encounters a yield, it will "return" from it at that point, but remember where it was so that when your iteration on your method resumes, it will resume from the point of the `yield return` that caused it to break out. If you wish to completely return, use `yield break`.

Comment: If you vant to break out, you can use `yield break`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth But the iterator method is not the `Create` method right?

Comment: @helb Yes it is. It allows you to write methods that can be consumed by enumerators and not run fully. Your code is only running what is asked of it based on how it is being iterated externally, just like the deferred methods in LINQ (they run only what they need to). If someone only asks for two items from your method and then cancels iterating, your method will only have run just enough code required to `yield` two items.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means your code is transformed into a state machine by the compiler.

When you call `Create` method, you'll get an `IEnumerable<T>`. You can then call `GetEnumerator()` on it and obtain an `IEnumerator<T>`.

Now, every time you call `MoveNext` on this iterator, your code will execute until it finds the first `yield` statement (whether it be `yield return` or `yield break`).

If it hits a `yield return x`, `MoveNext` returns true and the iterator's `Current` property will be set to `x`, and the rest of the code will be executed the next time you call `MoveNext`.

This happens until either there's no more code to run or the code hits a `yield break`. At that point, `MoveNext` will return false.

```
yield return 1;
yield return 2;
yield return 3;
```

Calling `MoveNext` on this piece of code will return true the first three times, and at each iteration, `Current` will be set to 1, 2 and 3.

**Edit 2**:

Regarding the `yield return ??` syntax, from Eric Lippert's [Ambiguous Optional Parentheses, Part Three](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/27/ambiguous-optional-parentheses-part-three.aspx)

> When they designed C# 2.0 they had this problem:
>
> `yield(x);`
>
> Does that mean "yield x in an iterator" or "call the yield method with argument x?" By changing it to
>
> `yield return(x);`
>
> it is now unambiguous; it cannot possibly mean "call the yield method".

Comment: Wow, you weren't joking when you said "code is transformed into a state machine". Inspecting the IL code revealed a lot of that black magic going on here ;-) Also, great answer!

Comment: @helb Indeed :) `yield` is one hell of a feature!

Answer (score 3):

The most important part of your quote is:

> and the current location in code is retained.

The iterator method does not return in a sense of exiting the method, otherwise you could only enumerate one item. `yield return` returns one element that is enumerated and then continues to run the code of the iterator method at the spot of the `yield return` in order to return the next elements when it encounters the next `yield return`.

An iterator method iterates over a collection and provides the single items by using `yield return`. These statements allow for a simplified implementation of the IEnumerable interface. In earlier versions of .NET, you had to implement a specific class as the enumerator. As this meant to introduce a lot of boilerplate code for each implementation of IEnumerable, the `yield` statements were introduced to create an iterator method in a simpler way. The `yield return` statements in the iterator method provide a signal to the compiler that a new element is to be returned. When building the project, the compiler transfers the iterator method to an implementation of IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2):

An iterator method like this will run until it finds a yield return whenever you fetch a new value from the iterator that it produces. I believe technically it is when you call the `MoveNext` method of the Enumerator.

When you call `MoveNext` the next time execution will resume from where it left off in the iterator method and keep going until it gets to the next yield return.

Essentially every call to yield return in your iterator method will yield one of the values in your final enumerable.