# IEnumerator stops after yield return new WaitForSeconds() unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I have a function that calls an `IEnumerator` but every time I try to run it the `IEnumerator` stops right after `yield return new`. It logs "start" in the debug but doesn't log "over".

```
public void StartAnimation()
{
   StartCoroutine(ResizeText());        
}

IEnumerator ResizeText()
{        
    Debug.Log("start");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    Debug.Log("over");
}
```

Comment: Do you expect this enumerator to return several things?

Comment: no just this one waitForSeconds line

Comment: and I want to write some lines after it

Comment: It won't never log end, because you're **returning** from function. Think about it, do you expect anything after simple function's `return`?

Comment: well then how do I wait for seconds in the middle of an IEnumerator?

Comment: If the problem is that `Debug.Log("over");` is not executed, that must be because `StartCoroutine` does not fully enumerate the enumerator. When you enumerate it fully, `Debug.Log("over");` executes on the second call to `MoveNext()`.

Comment: @YuriiN. It is [`yield return`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22064157/11683).

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: GSerg what do you mean by that? and how do I fix the problem?

Comment: @GSerg; What? Yes he expects it to run.. because it's valid behaviour. `yield return` is different from `yield break` when it comes to Coroutines.. `yield return` moves the coroutine's state to the next step/yield (equivalent to continue statement in a loop).. `yield break` will completely exit the coroutine without advancing the state (equivalent to a return statement of a function).. It makes sense. After all, Coroutines use `IEnumerator`.

Comment: @GSerg yeah, my bad, jumbled it with `yield break`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this code is perfectly valid (and it makes sense considering how Coroutines are implemented and how they work). It also makes sense because it's a `yield return` and not a `yield break`.. so technically the code should be working as is.

I also tried it in a blank Scene..

First, you are "probably" killing your scene before the time passes.

**Reproduce:**

Create a blank scene.. Add a script to the camera. Add:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(meh()); //OR: StartCoroutine("meh"); //Both will work just fine..
}

private IEnumerator meh()
{
    Debug.Log("Hello");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    Debug.Log("Bye");

}
```

When you run it, it will print "Hello", then it waits 2.0 seconds and it prints "Bye"..

Therefore, something else is missing/wrong in your scenario..

The only time the code will NOT run after a `yield` statement is when you do (`yield break`):

```
private IEnumerator meh()
{
    Debug.Log("Hello");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);

    Debug.Log("Bye");
    yield break;

    //NOTHING here will be executed because `yield break;` is like a permanent exit of the Coroutine..

    //Therefore these statements below will NOT execute..
    Debug.Log("Reboot");
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `yield return null;` at the end. You can omit it, all its doing is causing Unity to store a reference and execute the remainder of the function (nothing) for an extra frame.

Comment: @Draco18s; Correct. I don't need it but I have a bad habit of putting it ={

Comment: I hear ya. It can feel weird not-having a final return statement.